# how to display type of object of Elements array(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, children

//so, how would I find the workaround for the following

`s.getDescendants()=[THREE.Light,THREE.Mesh,THREE.Mesh]`

//what I want [THREE.Light,THREE.Mesh,THREE.Mesh]
//what I've gotten [object Object,object Object,object Object]

Answer (score 1):

you could access

```
 obj.constructor.name
```

on every single Object to get "Light", "Mesh" and "Mesh" but only if your three.js is not minified.

Answer (score 1):

In the [editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) I use this code to to that:

```
var getObjectType = function ( object ) {

    var types = {

        'Scene': THREE.Scene,
        'PerspectiveCamera': THREE.PerspectiveCamera,
        'AmbientLight': THREE.AmbientLight,
        'DirectionalLight': THREE.DirectionalLight,
        'HemisphereLight': THREE.HemisphereLight,
        'PointLight': THREE.PointLight,
        'SpotLight': THREE.SpotLight,
        'Mesh': THREE.Mesh,
        'Sprite': THREE.Sprite,
        'Object3D': THREE.Object3D

    };

    for ( var type in types ) {

        if ( object instanceof types[ type ] ) return type;

    }

};
```